# I have a csv file and wanted to form JSON objects by grouping using mutiple column of csv in java

Tags: java, json, csv

## >  **CSV Looks : With (,) sperated values**

```
    Col_1   Col_2   Col_5   Col_6

    1   YYY1    1111    CDX00001
    1   YYY2    1111    CDX00001

    2   YYY3    3333    CDX00002

    2   YYY4    2222    CDX00001

    2   YYY5    3333    CDX00002
    2   YYY6    3333    CDX00002
    2   YYY7    3333    CDX00002
    2   YYY8    4444    CDX00002
    2   YYY9    4444    CDX00002
```

## >         **I used below code to group 2 columns and JSON result looks like below .

```
     "CDX00002$@4444": [
        {
          "Col_5": "4444",
          "Col_6": "CDX00002",
          "Col_1": "2",
          "Col_2": "YYY8"
        },
        {
          "Col_5": "4444",
          "Col_6": "CDX00002",
          "Col_1": "2",
          "Col_2": "YYY9"
        }
      ],
      "CDX00002$@3333": [
        {
          "Col_5": "3333",
          "Col_6": "CDX00002",
          "Col_1": "2",
          "Col_2": "YYY3"
        },
        {
          "Col_5": "3333",
          "Col_6": "CDX00002",
          "Col_1": "2",
          "Col_2": "YYY5"
        },
        {
          "Col_5": "3333",
          "Col_6": "CDX00002",
          "Col_1": "2",
          "Col_2": "YYY6"
        },
        {
          "Col_5": "3333",
          "Col_6": "CDX00002",
          "Col_1": "2",
          "Col_2": "YYY7"
        }
      ],
      "CDX00001$@1111": [
        {
          "Col_5": "1111",
          "Col_6": "CDX00001",
          "Col_1": "1",
          "Col_2": "YYY1"
        },
        {
          "Col_5": "1111",
          "Col_6": "CDX00001",
          "Col_1": "1",
          "Col_2": "YYY2"
        },
        {
          "Col_5": "1111",
          "Col_6": "CDX00001",
          "Col_1": "2",
          "Col_2": "YYY10"
        }
      ],
      "CDX00001$@2222": [
        {
          "Col_5": "2222",
          "Col_6": "CDX00001",
          "Col_1": "2",
          "Col_2": "YYY4"
        }
      ]
    }
```

## > Code used :

```
                Map  namesByCompany = list.stream()
                          .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(item->item.get("Col_6") +"$@"+item.get("Col_5"),Collectors.toList()));

             Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create(); 
             System.out.println("--result---"+gson.toJson(namesByCompany));
```

=========================================================

> Details  :

```
But problem here my groupBy columns is dynamic and cannot be hard coded as above, If we get another one  columns then JSON should be prepared by considering new Groupby as well.  I need to prepare a JSON from CSV somehow using dynamic gorupby columns. I tried in java but if you any other tools or coding please post here . Thanks in advance
```

Answer (score 0):

If every row is one group, you can just make it add groups to the JSON of that group until it doesn't find another ',' .

Comment: Can you elaborate Delano?

Comment: When your data looks like this : 2,YY9,44,CDX00002;

retrieve all the parts in an array so : 

array A ['2','yy9','44','cdx00002'] 

so you take the first value and look for the next , put it in the array and then look from the location of that , for the next one and take the data between them. And go on until you reach ;

And build a json from that array.

This might be highly ineffective I don't know but this is what I would try.

Comment: I tried that way as well but it doesnt work. Do have any kind code which can help me please ?

Comment: please let me know if there is another way